# convert 01, 02, 03, 04 .. 09 to 1,2,3,4 ... 9

Tags: php, int

Hay how can I convert

```
01 to 1
02 to 2
```

all the way to 9?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I assume the input is a string?

```
$str = "01";
$anInt = intval($str);
```

You may think that the leading 0 would mean this is interpreted as octal, as in many other languages/APIs. However the second argument to intval is a base. The default value for this is 10. This means 09->9. See the first comment at the [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) page, which states that the base deduction you might expect only happens if you pass 0 in as the base.

Comment: If input is treated as an int, it will be handled as octal. (so 09->0)

Comment: Do `(int)$str;` instead. It's up to 4x faster than `intval()`.

Answer (score 3):

Do `(int)$str;` instead. It's up to 4x faster than `intval()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$x="01";
$x=+$x;

$x="02";
$x=+$x;

...
```

or

```
$x=+"01";
```

should work for both int, and string

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "05";
$last = $str[1];
```

Comment: the intval() solution is more reliable in this case, as it can catch "009" as well.

Comment: true. But my solution is faster, and the TS didn't say anything about the 009 :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = substr($input, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the generic regular expression solution: 's/[0]*([0-9])*/\1/' (add in anchors as appropriate)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str='05';

if(strpos($str,'0')==0 && strpos($str,'0') != false ){ 
 $new = intval(substr($str,1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the predefined php function .

```
intval()
```

For Ex:

```
 $convert =  intval(01);
 echo $convert ;
```

It will print 1(one);